# Tailwind is not arranging flex direction properly in chrome and other browsers

Tags: css, next.js, flexbox, formatting, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind in my next.js app. I am trying to arrange texts row-wise. It's not working as expected. Below is my short tailwind CSS code.

```
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div>01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

It's showing text one below another. I tried to change to col/ row both but no effect on text.
I also tried outside nextjs my simply creating html file and adding CSS inline to it. Still it's giving same result.
I tried to clear browser cache. Also, all my browser versions are updated.
It is expected to display -> 01 02 03 like this but showing one below another
Am I missing something?

I tried another properties such as `grow-0, flex-wrap, overflow-hidden etc.`

expected result should be 01 02 03
And it is displaying one below another

Comment: Consider checking the stylesheet that Tailwind generates is included in the HTML page. Also, consider checking the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the file that the code appears in.

Comment: Please take a look at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs and confirm that you have properly setup tailwindCSS. Also make sure to restart your development server if it is already running while you create the tailwind config.

Comment: Solved it by deleting .next folder and re-running development. Strange issue though.